# javascript onclick event in global custom text in views fields

Tags: javascript, drupal-6, view

I am not able to apply onclick event in global custom text field.

This is what i'm adding in custom field:

```
<a id="message_popup2" class="ViewUserProfile2" onclick="viewprofile2([uid])" >Changed & send password  </a> <br/>
```

and this is what view is result is :

```
<a id="message_popup2" class="ViewUserProfile2" Click="viewprofile2(2)" >Changed & send password  </a> <br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a display tpl of the view and using string replace, replace click by onclick

Answer (score 0):

in your view uid is probably used as string, not inserted as a variable

for MVC3 it would be something like @uid

**Updated after your edit:**

The result shows "Click=" .. that must be "onclick= "

Comment: only problem is that result must show "onlclick" instead of click.